# Multiple Shared Preference not saving/displaying data

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, indexoutofboundsexception

I searched for quite some time and to no avail as I still don't know why it's not working.

I am already using SharedPreference between one Activity and another

Code:

Saving Data

```
  SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

    editor.putString("email", email.getEmail().toString());
    editor.apply();
```

Retrieving Data

```
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String userEmail = preferences.getString("email", "defaultValue");

    DisplayEmail.setText(userEmail);
```

This code is working fine. But now, when moving on to the other shared preference, this happens:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.nathan.application/com.example.nathan.application.ActCamera}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2796)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2867)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1570)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6595)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
>        Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

The code due to this error:

```
 double Latitude = loc.getLatitude();
            double Longitude = loc.getLatitude();

            SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();


            editor.putString("Country", details.doInBackground().toString());
            editor.putLong("Latitude", Double.doubleToRawLongBits(Latitude));
            editor.putLong("Longitude", Double.doubleToRawLongBits(Longitude));

            editor.apply();


 SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

    Latitude = Double.longBitsToDouble(preferences.getLong("Latitude", 0));
    Longitude = Double.longBitsToDouble(preferences.getLong("Longitude", 0));
```

Comment: why don't you use your own sharedPref file?

Comment: something like this -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/23024962/6142219

Answer (score 0):

There have been instances where getDefaultSharedPreferences does not work as expected across different app contexts.

I would recommend you use:

```
Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
SharedPreferences preferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences("your_shared_preferences_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
```

Comment: I still have the same result :/

Comment: Are you sure it's a problem with the sharedPreferences and not with fetching the location coordinates?

Comment: They are being displayed in a textView beforehand, it has to be with sharedPreferences

Comment: Were you able to fix this problem @user7943?

Comment: What was the solution you used? @user7943

Answer (score 0):

> Multiple Shared Preference not saving/displaying data

This is called **multiprocess** **app**, where you define **two or more process in manifest class**. There is currently no way of safely accessing `SharedPreferences` on multiple processes, as described in its [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

**Solution :**

You will use **database based library tray** instead of SharedPreference if you want work with multiprocess.

https://github.com/grandcentrix/tray